# CSVWriter adds blank line beetween each row

Tags: java, csv, filewriter, opencsv

I am trying to write some data into a csv file but some of them are written at the end of the line and there is a blank space between each row. I have also tried do collect data into an ArrayList of strings and then use the method csvWriter.writeAll but it gives me the same result.

```
try(FileWriter fileWriter1 = new FileWriter(csvPath)){
        CSVWriter csvWriter = new CSVWriter(fileWriter1);
        //Impostazione di Git e della repo.
        Git git = Git.open(new File(Cpath));

        Repository repository = FileRepositoryBuilder.create(new File(Cpath));
        String repo = String.valueOf(repository);
        logger.info(repo);
        List<Ref> branches = git.branchList().call();
        for (Ref ref : branches)
        {

            logger.info(ref.getName());

        }

        Iterable<RevCommit> commits = git.log().all().call();

        for (RevCommit revCommit : commits) { //itero tutti i commit.

            String pattern = "MM/dd/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
            DateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(pattern);
            String date = df.format(revCommit.getAuthorIdent().getWhen());

            String[] columns = {date, revCommit.getFullMessage()};

            csvWriter.writeNext(new String[]{date, revCommit.getFullMessage()});



        }

        csvWriter.flush();
        csvWriter.close();

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

The CSV format loosely follows the RFC 4180. But most cvs writers consistenly use a `\r\n` (MS/DOS convention) end of file.

When you read that with an editor (or a terminal) that expects only one single `\n` for an end of line (Unix convention), you wrongly see additional lines when the file is perfectly correct.

---

Ref: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comma-separated_values)